# Automatic values for updated_at, created_at in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I want to make fields `updated_at` and `created_at` in my **Doctrine entities** to update automatically.

In Ruby on Rails models there are 2 fields: `updated_at` and `created_at`.

Description can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migration-overview:

> The timestamps macro adds two columns, created_at and updated_at. These special columns are automatically managed by Active Record if they exist.

Can I enable similar functionality in Doctrine 2?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

1. You can call `$this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime())` in `__construct` method.
2. You can use [Life Cycle Callbacks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)

```php
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
*/
public function updatedTimestamps(): void
{
    $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));    
    if ($this->getCreatedAt() === null) {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add into entity class notation:
`@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks`

Comment: Get an OOP example here- https://gist.github.com/lelledaniele/be67e03b51e04ab9f9b04b985ccd94e2

Comment: 3. in constructor use: `$this->publishedAt = new \DateTime();` and 
        `$this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();`

Comment: @VladimirCh that would also set the updatedAt even if nothing else in the entity is updated.

Comment: @marcguyer Not true, as the constructor will only be called on first creation by doctrine.

Comment: 'now' is not needed for `new \DateTime('now')`, since it's default value

Comment: @RobbertvandenBogerd Which constructor are you referring to? This is referring to life cycle callbacks. So, when `updatedTimestamps()` is called (on prepersist or preupdate), the updated_at value will be updated.

Answer (score 89):

This is another option if you would ever want to handle them separately.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Person
{
    ..........

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable = true)
     */
    protected $updated;


    /**
     * Gets triggered only on insert

     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime("now");
    }

    /**
     * Gets triggered every time on update

     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function onPreUpdate()
    {
        $this->updated = new \DateTime("now");
    }

    ..........
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but the fact that the `updated_at` gets a null value before first update can be a pain if you want to order by this field.

Comment: @El_Matella you just change the `onPrePersist()` function so it sets `created` and `updated` at the same time. Easily fixed in the DB if you didn't do this before in production as well.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did :)

Comment: How can we insert current DateTime in createdAt field using Yml file?

Comment: @rashidkhan I don't think you can. You need to handle it inside the PHP class.

Comment: Well, [you *can* specify the `lifeCycleCallbacks` in the YAML](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-callbacks), but that won't save you from defining the public method (+ the logic) inside the class.

Comment: Very good. For future users, don't forget to add @ORM\HasLifecyleCallbacks in the class annotations (would have saved me some time).

Answer (score 28):

The most convinient solution for me is `Timestampable` feature of [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html).

Simple configuration and later you are able to make fields `createdAt` and `updatedAt` of `Entity` filled out automatically by adding two simple `annotations` like:

`@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable(on="create")`

and/or

`@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable(on="update")`

e.g.

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $updatedAt;
```

Without any redundant code in pure `PHP`.

Comment: This is the best solution if you already use StofDoctrineExtensions (probably most of us). It should be noted that you need to enable timestampable though: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/configuration.html#activate-the-extensions-you-want

Comment: With Symfony 4.0+  `composer require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle` to install (using Flex)

Comment: I am using this approach with symfony Flex, the only missing part for me was that I had to update `./config/bundles.php` to contain Stof bundle: `Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle::class => ['all' => true],`

Answer (score 9):

You can implement it as a trait as well - like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Traits;

use DateTime;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Exception;

/**
 * Trait TimeStampableTrait
 * @package App\Entity\Trait
 */
trait TimeStampableTrait
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @return DateTimeInterface|null
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function getCreatedAt(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt ?? new DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTimeInterface $createdAt
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTimeInterface|null
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt ?? new DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTimeInterface $updatedAt
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function updateTimestamps(): void
    {
        $now = new DateTime();
        $this->setUpdatedAt($now);
        if ($this->getId() === null) {
            $this->setCreatedAt($now);
        }
    }
}
```

Add this trait to your entity (and don't forget `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` notation):

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Traits\TimeStampableTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MyEntityRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class MyEntity
{
    use TimeStampableTrait;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you want to have some entities with only **"createdAt"** column, and may be other entities with only **"updatedAt"** column, and of course some entities with both columns **"createdAt"** and **"updatedAt"**. You can create 3 traits :

```
src/Entity/Traits/Timestamping/
src/Entity/Traits/Timestamping/AutoCreatedAtTrait.php
src/Entity/Traits/Timestamping/AutoUpdatedAtTrait.php
src/Entity/Traits/Timestamping/TimestampableTrait.php
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Traits\Timestamping;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ThisTrait adds createdAt field to entity.
 */
trait AutoCreatedAtTrait
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTimeInterface $createdAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @return \DateTimeInterface
     */
    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedAtValue(): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Traits\Timestamping;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ThisTrait adds updatedAt field to entity.
 */
trait AutoUpdatedAtTrait
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTimeInterface $updatedAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @return \DateTimeInterface
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setUpdatedAtValue(): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Traits\Timestamping;

/**
 * ThisTrait adds Timestampable fields to entity.
 */
trait TimestampableTrait
{
    use AutoCreatedAtTrait, AutoUpdatedAtTrait;
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Traits\Timestamping\AutoCreatedAtTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OnlyCreationDateEntityRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class OnlyCreationDateEntity
{
    use AutoCreatedAtTrait;
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Traits\Timestamping\TimestampableTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BothColumnsEntityRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class BothColumnsEntity
{
    use TimestampableTrait;
}
```

And don't forget to add into entity class notation: `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks`

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using timestampable trait

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-doctrine/timestampable

```
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

class Article
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
}
```

will add all appropriate functionality automatically

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights. If this is the case here, please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it