# symfony 4 doctrine error inserting new object with auto generated DATETIME and default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to insert my object in my MariaDB database with Doctrine and symfony4

My table contains a `DATETIME` column `timestamp` with a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Doctrine is crashing when calling `persist()` with the following error:

`Could not convert PHP value 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' of type 'string' to type 'datetime'. Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime`

I do not understand why because this is supposed to be auto generated by the database on insert. Am I supposed to provide a "datetime" ? Is there a fix for this please ?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Change your database 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
Type to varchar or text

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was using doctrine lifecycle event and use the `onPrePersist` and/or `onPreUpdate` event.

The full solution is described [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29770179/529403) and [in the official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/doctrine/events.html).

This way I was able to save the current time in a timestamp column using Symfony 4.4.